# limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}-\frac{1}{n}(\log(\frac{1}{n}))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can I conclude that the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}-\frac{1}{n}(\log(\frac{1}{n}))$ is $0$? If $\log(\frac{1}{n})$ was bounded we can argue by the fact that:

A sequence which converges to $0$ times another bounded sequence converges to $0$ as well. But $\log(\frac{1}{n})$ is not bounded.

Comment: Use L'hopital rule : $x\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{\ln(n)}{n} \to 0 ~~~~~~~ \text{as}~~~ n\to +\infty$$

For example you can use De L'Hôpital rule, or simply the hierarchy of infinities.

(The property I have used is simply $\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = -\ln(n)$).

Answer (score 3):

With $x:=\ln n$ this becomes $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=0$, which is true because $\int_1^\infty xe^{-x}dx=2/e$ is finite, with a continuous non-negative integrand that monotonically decreases.

Comment: Can you please explain the integral argument? Im not very familiar with it

Comment: @DatBoi: Ah, sorry. Suppose $f(x)\ge0$ is monotonically decreasing and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges. To show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, suppose to the contrary; then there is an $\epsilon$ so that given any $n$ we can find an $x_n\ge n$ where $f(x_n)\ge\epsilon$ (this is just the negation of the existence of the limit). However, since the function is monotonically decreasing, $\int_0^{x_n}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge n\epsilon$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, the integral does not converge.

Comment: @robjohn thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Since $n^{1/n} \to 1$ and $\ln$ is continuous, we get

$$\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\right) \to \ln 1 =0.$$